# Map with Long key does not work in Serializable class

Tags: java, google-app-engine, serialization, jetty

I have a Serializable class, with a map property. When the map has a Long as key the code does not work, while with String it works.

This doesn't work:

```
public class UserSession implements Serializable {
    Map<Long, Date> timeQuestionAsked = new HashMap<>();
}
```

This does work:

```
public class UserSession implements Serializable {
        Map<String, Date> timeQuestionAsked = new HashMap<>();
    }
```

The weird thing I get no exception. This class is loaded in a filter in Jetty (google app engine app), and when I try to use the class with the Long key, I get a weird "Not found" error.

Comment: How does it not work exactly? A stack trace and the serialization code would be useful.

Comment: Can't reproduce it. Please post a [minimal, complete example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which shows the behavior.

Comment: Note that `java.lang.Long` implements `Serializable`, so there is no inherent problem with using it as the key type in a `Map` that is intended to be serialized.

Comment: @Radiodef working on a minimal example...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually it was caused by the database framework I was using: objectify. It turns out Maps must have string as keys: https://code.google.com/p/objectify-appengine/wiki/Entities#Maps

It has nothing to do with Serializable...